# Handle SSL connections from an inetd ruby script

Tags: ruby, openssl, inetd

I'd like to run a Ruby script that handles encrypted communications from inetd. As I need the certificate information for further processing, I can't "offload" the SSL to something like stunnel.

In order to do so, I'd have to somehow use STDIN and STDOUT with the Ruby SSL object. Unfortunately, the OpenSSL:SSL:SSLSocket only accepts an IO in its constructor. Is there a way to tie STDIN and STDOUT to an IO, so that it reads from standard input and writes to standard output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$stdin` and `$stdout` can be interchangeably used as `IO` objects. You may pass them to the SSLSocket. Does that help? Otherwise I'd need more code to help you out.

Comment: They don't work directly, but adding some additional calls make SSLSocket accept standard input and standard output just fine:
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(Socket.for_fd($stdin.fileno))